# How can PDE matrices be identified?

Tags: pde

I need to include experimental results for lots of PDE (partial differential equation) matrices in my research work. How can I identify PDE matrices? For example, matrices in [the UFL Sparse Matrix Collection](http://yifanhu.net/GALLERY/GRAPHS/search.html).

Answer (score 2):

For the UF sparse matrix collection, you can search for "PDE" in the keyword section and 8 results will appear. The notes section for many of the entries will indicate the provenance of the example.

Another strategy you can employ is to look at examples in packages like PETSc, FEniCS, deal.II, and others that are commonly used to solve PDEs. It should be possible to modify the code in these examples to write the coefficients of linear systems to disk to get additional examples of "PDE matrices".

Comment: Indeed, you could just take the example programs of deal.II and in the `solve()` function of each of them just do something along the lines of `system_matrix.print(std::cout);`.